# Do I need a server to send PDFs created in my app to the same app (different account) on another device?

Tags: java, android, firebase, send, file-sharing

Beginner here.

I'm creating an app in Android Studio (Java) where the user can create and store PDFs on the app and send these to another account on the same app, on a different device.

The user will have a list of contacts stored in a database.

Do I need a server to do this? Are there any tutorials online showing one how to code this? (I've been searching for hours but can't find anything specific to my problem. Maybe I'm wording it wrong...)

I was looking into Firebase but I'm completely lost on where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases you don't need a server, you can use firebase instead. Currently, they have a storage feature that lets you store files on their servers and retrieve them later.

Here is the official documentation [firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)

One thing you could do is upload the file from android device and download from another one.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to send the file from one device to the other without the receiving user having to go on and download it themselves?

Comment: It depends on the use case. One way would be to send an android notification with the download link

Comment: You could send an email with the pdf attached.